# Как сохранить html страницу при парсинге

Tags: java, android, jsoup, парсер

Хочу сделать возможность сохранять нужную страницу с интернета в html, чтобы потом данные парсить офлайн именно с этой страницы, которую сохранил на устройстве. Пользуюсь библиотекой Jsoup. Помогите пожалуйста, как это можно осуществить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё просто.

1. Загружаете страницу.
2. Получаете её в виде HTML кода методом `getOutherHtml()` класса `Element`, от коего наследуется, в т.ч. и класс `Document`. Т.е. вы можете сделать что-то типа

`String html = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get().getOutherHtml();`

3. Теперь сохраняйте любым способом. В файл, БД, SharedPreferences, как угодно.

Comment: Спасибо) По ходу мб буду задавать вопросы)

Answer (score 2):

Без использования Jsoup:

```
class DownloadHtmlFromSiteToFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count;
    byte[] buff = new byte[64];
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream out = null;

    try {
        is = new URL("http://google.com").openStream();
        out = new FileOutputStream("D:/google.html");

        while ((count = is.read(buff)) != -1) {
            out.write(buff, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (IOException e){}
}
```